# How to add +1 to a text value every click i do?

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

I want to add +1 to a text value but when I click it doesn't add anything...
I think is a updating time but i am not sure...

```
<input type="text" id="cliccare" value="0">
<img src="http://www.sinalphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-copyright.png" class="click" onclick="clicca()"/>
punticlick = 1;
punti = document.getElementById("cliccare").value ;
function clicca() {
    punti += punticlick;
}
```

I don't really know if it is correct the `onclick` on the `img`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add punticlick to punti, it makes no sense: in javascript, `punti += punticlick` equals to `punti = punti + punticlick`. Instead, you have to do this:

```
punticlick = 0;
punti = document.getElementById("cliccare");
function clicca(){
punticlick++;
punti.value = punticlick;
}
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jn9dqfp4/1/

Comment: It adds 1 (++ in javascript). The problem is that puntclick was initially set to 1. I edited the answer, check the fiddle again.

Comment: i copied the fiddle and paste... it adds 2 in my html but it adds 1 in fiddle.... wtf?

Answer (score 1):

`punti = document.getElementById("cliccare").value` is outside the function `clicca`. So on every click it wont get new value

Secondly since you will add one you can directly add with `punti`. I dont see any use of second variable

Thirdly once you have updated the value of `punti` you need to update value of the DOM

```
function clicca(){
punti = parseInt(document.getElementById("cliccare").value,10) ; // Convert to integer
punti += 1;
document.getElementById("cliccare").value=punti
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/e7yyLu0o/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A very shortcut (mostly discouraged) way is like this

```js
cliccare.onclick = e => ++e.target.value
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cliccare" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just set onclick attribute:

onclick="document.getElementById('cliccare').value++"

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="cliccare" value="0">
           <img src="http://www.sinalphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-copyright.png" class="click" onclick="clicca()"/>
<script>               
 var pun = 1;
            punti = document.getElementById("cliccare").value ;
            function clicca(){
            punti=pun;
            document.getElementById("cliccare").value=punti;
            pun++;
            }
</script>
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick` attribute for almost any html tag, but the code snippet you've wrote won't work, because after the increment of the value you need to set that value back into **input** tag, so your java script part would look like this:

```
  <script>
      punticlick = 1;

      function clicca() {
          punti = document.getElementById("cliccare").value;
          punti += punticlick;
          document.getElementById("cliccare").value = punti;
      }
  </script>
```